# В Java объект типа Scanner связанный с файлом для считывания текста не получается использовать больше 1 раза

Tags: java, файлы, scanner

Собственно,сам код.Сначала нужно посчитать количество строк в коде,затем внести их в массив:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("фильмы.txt");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(file);

        int count = 0;
        while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
            scanFile.nextLine();
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
            }


            String slova[] = new String[count];
         for (int i = 0;i < slova.length;i++){
            slova[i] = scanFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(slova[i]);
        }

        }


    }
```

При запуске выдаёт следующее:

```
1
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
2
3
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
4
5
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:21)
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Я переписал код с использованием 2х сканеров:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("фильмы.txt");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(file);

        int count = 0;
        while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
            scanFile.nextLine();
            count++;
            System.out.println(count);
        }
        scanFile.close();

        String slova[] = new String[count];
        Scanner scanFile2 = new Scanner(file);
        for (int i = 0;i < slova.length;i++){
            slova[i] = scanFile2.nextLine();
            System.out.println(slova[i]);
        }
        scanFile2.close();
    }


    }
```

И теперь всё работает как надо:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
the shawshank redemption
the godfather
the dark knight
schindler's list
pulp fiction
the lord of the rings
the good the bad and the ugly
fight club
the lord of the rings
forrest gump
star wars
inception
the lord of the rings
the matrix
samurai
star wars
city of god
the silence of the lambs
batman begins
die hard
chinatown
room
dunkirk
fargo
no country for old men

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Собственно,интересует,в чём проблема в первой версии кода?Почему не получилось использовать один сканер для двух циклов?

Comment: Вы прочитали 25 строк файла, далее вы запрашиваете 26ю строку и получаете сообщение, что ее не существует.

Comment: @Maxim , спасибо,теперь понятно.А можно как то изменить код,что бы с использованием того же сканера всё работало?Пробовал применить после 1 цикла к сканеру методы remove() и reset(),проблема осталась та же

Comment: @Zebsier а зачем вам вообще дважды читать один и тот же файл? Если вы первый раз читаете только ради определения количества строк для создания затем массива нужного размера, то, может, просто использовать список вместо массива? Уж больно неэффективно выглядит текущее решение, если всё именно так...

Comment: @Regent в рамках этого задания нельзя пользоваться списком,оно должно быть сделано через сканеры и массивы,поэтому и приходиться читать файл два раза,просто мне интересно почему при использовании одного сканера дважды,программа работает не корректно,а при использовании 2 сканеров всё работает как надо

Comment: @Zebsier `Scanner` нельзя перезапустить, поэтому если вы хотите дважды читать файл, то придётся создавать два сканера. Насчет "нельзя использовать списки" - ладно, но и с помощью только массивов можно обойтись без двух чтений: достаточно написать эдакую мини-реализацию `ArrayList`. То есть создаёте массив на Х (выбранная вами константа) элементов. Если при очередном чтении строки массив полон, создаёте массив большего размера (например, в два раза), копируете в него значения из старого и продолжаете цикл. Тут уж что нужно тем, кто проверяет задание...

Comment: @Regent , спасибо